# Symfony2 translations from Database?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

how to make a dynamic translation in symfony2 ?

I know the simple translation method , But I want to translate some data of **database** ..

Comment: Do you want to translate database entries, or do you want to save your translations inside the database?

Comment: yes , I want to translate database entries .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to translate database entries you can use one of the following bundles (according to the offical symfony docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-database-content):
https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions

I don't know much about DoctrineBehaviors. But we are using DoctrineExtensions and it's working pretty good.

UPDATE: We switched to KnpDoctrineBehaviors because of the simpler architecture. I'd recommend to go with it!

Comment: Thanks :) , what about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363394/get-twig-golbals-from-database