# Get twig golbals from database?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

i Want to get the get the twig Globals from the DataBase , Can I ?

```
# app/config/parameters.yml

    twig:
        globals:
            siteName: 'here site name from database'
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what exactly you want ? What does the database have to do with Twig ? Do you want access in your code to the values defined under `globals` ?

Comment: for example I have a table contient all my site data ... i want to call the name of the site from this table ... and set it as a twig global :)

Comment: An event listener can be used to pull values from the database and add them to twig globals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862801/service-method-as-twig-global-variable/28863725#28863725

Answer (score 1):

You can create a TwigExtension (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html and http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension), Inject the EntityManager in it and register the globals there.

Comment: Good but this is an extension , not a globals ? right  ... 
so i will call it like this ? {{ 'name'|globals }}
no like this ? {{ globals }}

Comment: create a twig function to accomplish this issue and not a twig extension.( you write a twig function like this: {{ my_function(param1, param2) }} )

Answer (score 0):

Load the global values in the BaseController

```
$this->get('twig')
    ->addGlobal(
        'global1',
        $this->em
             ->getRepository('MyBundle:Globals')
             ->getGlobalOne());
```